# Selecting td's based on class in a nested table using Prototype - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, prototype

I'm working on some legacy code that has a table within another table. Both have ids. I need to select the tds in that nested table that have a particular class attribute. This is using Prototype... again a byproduct of it being legacy code. How could I select all of the particular tds and traverse them?

`<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">
    <table id="tableIWant">
      <tr>
         <td class="classIWant"></td>
         <td class></td>
         <td class="classIWant"></td>
         <td class></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>`

So I want to select the all of the tds with class="classIWant" in the table with id="tableIWant" using the Prototype framework. How may I do this?

-Thanks from a newbie engineer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$$` to select with a CSS style selector in Prototype.

`var allTds = $$('#tableIWant td.classIWant');`

to iterate over then:

```
allTds.each(function(td) {
    // Set background to red on selected tds.
    td.style.background = '#f00';
});
```